# Data can not be saved after the transition between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, catransition

### The purpose for my app

- I have two ViewControllers,`FrontSideViewController` and `BackSideViewController`, in my little project.
- I am about to flipping `FrontSideViewController` to `BackSideViewController` through using `CATransition` while each ViewController's data can be saved.

### Describe of Problem

1. The views transited in the unexpected way which `animation` is not seem like the `UIAnimationTransition.FlipFromLeft(or)Right` thing.
2. After flipping views, the previous view's data can not be saved, which means when I flipped back the old view, its tiny data (something like `textField's text`) is just gone.

[image: gif]

### My Code

- Same Logical function to flip between the views which be used in two `Classes`.

`FrontSideViewController.swift`

```
class FrontSideViewController: UIViewController {

var frontSideViewController: FrontSideViewController?
var backSideViewController: BackSideViewController?
var frontSide: Bool = true
@IBOutlet weak var flip_1Button: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    frontSideViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FrontSideViewController") as? FrontSideViewController
    backSideViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BackSideViewController") as? BackSideViewController
    flip_1Button.addTarget(self, action: "flipViews", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func textFieldDoneEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
}

func flipViews() {

    UIView.beginAnimations("ViewSwitch", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.6)
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(.EaseInOut)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(.FlipFromLeft, forView: view, cache: true)
    backSideViewController?.view.frame = self.view.frame
    frontSideViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    frontSideViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    frontSideViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(backSideViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(backSideViewController!.view)
    backSideViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

}
}

`BackSideViewController.swift`

```
class BackSideViewController: UIViewController {

var frontSideViewController: FrontSideViewController?
var backSideViewController: BackSideViewController?
@IBOutlet weak var flip_2Button: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    frontSideViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FrontSideViewController") as? FrontSideViewController
    backSideViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BackSideViewController") as? BackSideViewController

    flip_2Button.addTarget(self, action: "flipViews", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func flipViews() {

    UIView.beginAnimations("ViewSwitch", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.6)
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(.EaseInOut)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(.FlipFromRight, forView: view, cache: true)
    frontSideViewController?.view.frame = self.view.frame
    backSideViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    backSideViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    backSideViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(frontSideViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(frontSideViewController!.view)
    frontSideViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Please teach me how solve those two problems.

Thanks for your help.

Ethan Joe

Comment: Ok, first of all, why are you instantiating a FrontSideViewController inside an instance of FrontSideViewController?

Comment: Your controller structure is incorrect. You should have a custom container controller that adds FrontSideViewController or BackSideViewController as a child. The reason your data disappears is that you're instantiating new controllers each time you flip. The container controller should have  properties that point to the instances of FrontSideViewController and BackSideViewController so they don't get deallocated.

Comment: The thing is, the `container viewController` is the source of problem in the my previous version app! The normal viewController structure like you said, the container view controller with other subViewControllers, the viewController hierarchy in my old version app,can not implement my require for I/O of Data. That is the reason why I tried to implement View Transition without container ViewController.

Comment: I don't think this approach can be made to work. You should try again to implement it with the container view controller, and if you can't get the data I/O to work, ask a specific question about that. I don't see why that wouldn't work. The parent has access to the children, and the children have access to the parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answering, man. I am trying to change my strategy, one viewController + ViewFlip + Hidden Objects, which can work without Container ViewController.